# Powershell copy some folders from a zip file

Tags: powershell

I have a zip folder it contains 10-12 folders (in folders i have some file) with different names and i need to get folders and copy into destination whose name contains 'abc' or 'xyz' like that using Power Shell Scripting.

Thanks in advance,
Chinna V

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function Extract-Zip{
param([string]$zipfilename, [string] $destination)

if(test-path($zipfilename))
{    
    $shellApplication = new-object -com shell.application
    $zipPackage = $shellApplication.NameSpace($zipfilename)
    $destinationFolder = $shellApplication.NameSpace($destination)
    $destinationFolder.CopyHere($zipPackage.Items())
}
```

}

This should unzip your compressed file to the destination of your choice.  Alternatively, you can explore PS Community Extensions - http://pscx.codeplex.com

Comment: I need to copy only the folders whose name contains "abc" or "xyz" not all the folders.... it means we need to write contains/like statement to get only those folders.. i have tried but no luck.. can you plz help me on this. Thanks in advance, Chinna V

Comment: ###########################################################  
# COMMENT : Search zip files for specific files and extract 
#           them to a (temp) directory. 
########################################################### 
#ERROR REPORTING ALL 
Set-StrictMode -Version latest 

#----------------------------------
#STATIC VARIABLES 
#----------------------------------
$srcZipFilepath = “C:\Test\ZIPFILE.zip”
$tempPath = “C:\Temp” 
$ABCDestination = “C:\Test123\ABC”
$XYZDestination = “C:\Test123\XYZ”
$PQRDestination = “C:\Test123\PQR”

Comment: #----------------------------------
#FUNCTION CopyFilesToFolders 
#----------------------------------
Function CopyFilesToFolders 
{ 
  Param([string]$tempPath) 

 #Write-Host $tempPath + "11"
 #Loop through each folder copy in destination
 $shell_app= New-Object -com shell.application
 $file = Get-ChildItem -Path $tempPath  
 foreach($filist in $file) 
 { 
  #Write-Host $filist.Name + "21"  
  if ($filist.Name -like "*XYZ*")  
   {

Comment: if (!(Test-Path -path $XYZDestination )) 
    { 
      New-Item $XYZDestination  -type directory
    }  
    #Write-Host $filist.fullname + "- XYZ -" + $XYZDestination      
    Move-Item -Path $filist.fullname -Destination $XYZDestination  
   } 
   elseif($filist.Name -like "*ABC*")
    {
      if (!(Test-Path -path $ABCDestination)) 
      { 
       New-Item $ABCDestination -type directory
      }  
      #Write-Host $filist.fullname + "- Services -" + $ABCDestination     
      Move-Item -Path $filist.fullname -Destination $ABCDestination    
   }

Comment: else
   {
    if (!(Test-Path -path $PQRDestination)) 
      { 
       New-Item $PQRDestination -type directory
      }  
      #Write-Host $filist.fullname + "- Application Location -" + $PQRDestination      
      Move-Item -Path $filist.fullname -Destination $PQRDestination     
   }
 }
  #Deleting the temp folder
  ReMove-Item -Path $tempPath 
}

Comment: #---------------------------------------------------------- 
#FUNCTION CopyFiles ----
Function CopyFiles 
{
  #Unzip the files and copy in temp folders
  $shell_app= New-Object -com shell.application
  $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $srcZipFilepath  
  foreach($file in $files) 
  {
    $zip_files = $shell_app.namespace($file.FullName) 
    if (!(Test-Path -path $tempPath)) 
    { 
     New-Item $tempPath -type directory
    } 
    $copyHere = $shell_app.namespace($tempPath) 
    $copyHere.Copyhere($zip_files.items()) 
  }
 CopyFilesToFolders $tempPath  
}
CopyFiles 
Write-Host "SCRIPT FINISHED"